Get top 1 set duplicate from the table
How to get top 1 set duplicate from the list
I have below table xyz with following data
Id  Name      Mobile           Email              
1   k1       900000001        k1@gmail.com         
2   k2       900000001        k2@gmail.com         
3   k1       900000000        k1@gmail.com   
4   k2       900000001        k2@gmail.com 
5   k1       900000000        k1@gmail.com

Output
Id      Name      Mobile           Email              
3       k1       900000000        k1@gmail.com  
5       k1       900000000        k1@gmail.com

Some scenerio may be data will be like  below no duplicates
Id      Name      Mobile           Email              
1       k1       900000000        k1@gmail.com         
2       k2       900000001        k2@gmail.com 

Output should be no output

Checking my understanding - are you looking for the (name, mobile, email) combination that repeats the most times, at least twice?

duplicate set records are there in my table of (name,mobile,email) combination need top 1 record set, if there is not duplicate no data should appear. @Mureinik

Seems like a "spin" on the classic Get top 1 row of each group. First get rows that have duplicates, using COUNT, and then get the first of those rows, using (DENSE_)RANK (instead of ROW_NUMBER):
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (Id int,
                            Name char(2),
                            Mobile varchar(13),
                            Email nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES(1,'k1','900000000','k1@gmail.com         '),
      (2,'k2','900000001','k2@gmail.com         '),
      (3,'k1','900000000','k1@gmail.com   '),
      (4,'k2','900000001','k2@gmail.com '),
      (5,'k1','900000000','k1@gmail.com');
GO

WITH C AS(
    SELECT Id,
           Name,
           Mobile,
           Email,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) AS Cnt --Or perhaps (PARTITION BY Name, Mobile, Email) based on latest revision
    FROM dbo.YourTable),
R AS(
    SELECT Id,
           Name,
           Mobile,
           Email,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS Rnk --Or perhaps (ORDER BY Name, Mobile, Email) based on latest revision
    FROM C
    WHERE Cnt > 1)
SELECT Id,
       Name,
       Mobile,
       Email
FROM R
WHERE Rnk = 1;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
GO
    

